# Powershell - How would I return appname from a foreach loop only if status code -ne 200?

Tags: powershell, foreach

The title says it all.  I have been returning output from every iteration of both of the below foreach loops (see the Write-Host and Write-Output lines), but the application that is using this script (Nagios) can't handle that much data.  Therefore, I would like to only return 1 output at a time.  Basically "All apps okay" or "app(s) down: then list the apps not returning 200 response code".
I have no idea how to do this as getting the foreach loops to work in the first place was quite the challenge for me.

```
$ok = 0
$warning = 1
$critical = 2
$unknown = 3

$appPool = get-webapplication
$errorcode = 0
$time_errorcode = 0

foreach($a in $appPool) {

    $app = $a.Attributes[0].Value;
    $url = "http://localhost$app/apitest/index"
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $HTTP_Response = try{ $HTTP_Request.GetResponse() }catch {$exceptionMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $exceptionItem = $app}

    [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode -ne 200 
    $statuscode = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
    Write-Host "$app status code: $statuscode"
    if ($HTTP_Response.StatusCode.value__ -ne 200) {
        [int]$errorcode = 1
    }
}

foreach($t in $appPool){
    $app = $t.Attributes[0].Value;
    $url = "http://localhost$app/apitest/index"
    $output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
    $start_time = Get-Date

    try {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output} catch {
    $exceptionMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $exceptionItem = $app
    Write-Output "$app error: $exceptionMessage"}
    Write-Output "$app Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).milliSeconds) millisecond(s)"
    $timetaken = $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).milliSeconds)
    if ($timetaken.StatusCode.value__ -ge 500) {
        [int]$time_errorcode = 1
    }
}
#Uncomment for testing
#Write-Output $time_errorcode
#Write-Output $errorcode

if (($errorcode -eq 0 -and $time_errorcode -eq 0)){exit $ok}
if (($errorcode -eq 1 -and $time_errorcode -eq 0)){exit $critical}
if (($errorcode -eq 0 -and $time_errorcode -eq 1)){exit $warning}
if (($errorcode -eq 1 -and $time_errorcode -eq 1)){exit $critical}
else {exit $unknown}
```

Comment: My first instinct would suggest using `Where-Object`. I am not sure where or how to include it in your example. Simply put, store everything in an array and then use `Where-Object` to check against to determine which output to show.

Comment: `$timetaken.StatusCode.value__ -ge 500` is obviously a typo. Also, please explain why you have **2** loops. Apart from that, what you asked is trivial, I can help you if I had more info.

Comment: @marsze it's not a typo.  That section of the code is meant to check if the app download takes longer than 500ms.  In fact that's also why I have 2 loops.  1 to check the response code, and a second to check the download time.  What more info do you need?

Comment: `$timetaken` is a number (btw you probably meant to use `TotalMilliseconds`) and has no property `StatusCode`. What you meant was probably: `if (((Get-Date) - $start_time).TotalMilliseconds -gt 500)`

Comment: Alrighty- I'll give that a shot.  What about being able to Write-Output singular apps when they error (or when they are gt 500 in the second loop)?  I would like to write only the apps that failed rather than all of them in order to conserve data that is being reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach. UNTESTED. Just to give you an idea to work with.

```
$appPool = Get-WebApplication
$errorcode = 0
$time_errorcode = 0

# Using a hashset ensures every app is contained only once
$appsDown = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"

foreach($a in $appPool) {
    $app = $a.Attributes[0].Value;
    $url = "http://localhost$app/apitest/index"

    ### Test response code ###

    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $HTTP_Response = $null
    try {
        $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    } catch {
        # for test
        Write-Host $_
    }
    if ($null -eq $HTTP_Response -or [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode -ne 200 ) {
        [int]$errorcode = 1
        [void]$appsDown.Add($app)
    }

    ### Test response time ###

    $output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
    $start_time = Get-Date
    $timetaken = -1
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
        $timetaken = ((Get-Date) - $start_time).TotalMilliSeconds
    } catch {
        # for test
        Write-Host $_
    }
    if ($timetaken -lt 0 -or $timetaken -ge 500) {
        [int]$time_errorcode = 1
        [void]$appsDown.Add($app)
    }
}

# Output the results here
if ($appsDown.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "All apps okay"
}
else {
    Write-Output ($appsDown.Count.ToString() + "app(s) down")
    $appsDown | sort | foreach {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}

if (($errorcode -eq 0 -and $time_errorcode -eq 0)){exit $ok}
if (($errorcode -eq 1 -and $time_errorcode -eq 0)){exit $critical}
if (($errorcode -eq 0 -and $time_errorcode -eq 1)){exit $warning}
if (($errorcode -eq 1 -and $time_errorcode -eq 1)){exit $critical}
else {exit $unknown}
```

**Explanations:**

```
$appsDown = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
```

Create a new instance of a [.NET HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to hold the app names. (It's an unordered collection where every value is stored only once.)

```
[void]$appsDown.Add($app)
```

Add the app name to the collection. `[void]` is there to prevent the method's return value to be sent to the pipeline.

Comment: This is perfect and worked like a charm, thank you.  I would like to also understand it so I have some follow up questions.  First up what does this section do? `[void]$appsDown.Add($app)` Second I have not seen this before, what is it's purpose as well? `New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"`

Comment: @RaptorPete I'v added some explanations to my answer, hope it helps. If this solved your problem, mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I am just realizing today that your example will report an app is "down" if the download time takes longer than 500ms.  Ultimately I would want it to include a separate output for a time_errorcode rather than just "app is down".  Something like `"$currentapp warning - download time 850ms"`
That being said, within your if/else statement that outputs the results I can't seem to figure out a way to easily include this section.  You are reporting any apps down to a collection, but is it possible to also report the specific times to that collection and output those?

Comment: @RaptorPete You have several options. You could make multiple collections,  collections of custom objects, output per iteration etc. It all depends on what exactly you want to output and how. Give it a try and if you need more help feel free to extend your original question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$list = @()
Foreach(x in y){
$item = @{}
If(x.error -eq 200){
$item.Name = x.Name
}
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item
$list += $obj
}
```

Adding these parts will leave you with a list of appsnames in the variable `$list`

Comment: It looks like you have this list built only if the error equals 200.  How would I return the app name if the error is something other than 200?

Comment: The if statement I've added here is just an example.
Its more to show you how to construct a list, You need to add the Variables, list, item, and the object creation in the relevant places.